# Can I modify a failed Laravel (redis/horizon) job payload before retrying?

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-queue, laravel-horizon

Locally, I use the database queue driver, but on production, we use Redis with Horizon.

Recently, I noticed a job failed due to a tiny issue in the payload (a single character). I'd really like to modify the payload and resend it because having the user re-perform the steps to generate the job isn't feasible. If the payload was stored in the database, I could easily accomplish this, but I'm not as familiar with Redis, and I'm wondering if it's something I can do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. But what I found so far is not promising. If you change the payload manually laravel cannot deserialize it. It is safety feature for data injection I guess just like JWT. A key is generated from the content of the payload and when the key is parsed and not equals with the payload it fails.

Comment: I am thinking I have to create an interface for failed jobs. I can easily retrive the data from the failed_jobs table. 
$jsonpayload = json_decode($payload);
$data = unserialize($jsonpayload->data->command);
Display the data, manipulate it, where it is necessary and then hit save, which creates a new job and a new serialized data. This is more like a workaround than a proper solution.